# Python `itertools.chain` equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, python, collections, iteration, combinations

Is there an equivalent of python's [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for Java (with third-party libraries or without)?

```
itertools.chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) # -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Something like this:

```
new Iterable<E> {
       public Iterator<E> iterator() {
           return new Iterator<E>() {
               Iterator<E> i1 = list1.iterator();
               Iterator<E> i2 = list2.iterator();
               public boolean hasNext() {
                   return i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext();
               }
               public E next() {
                   if(i1.hasNext()) {
                       return i1.next();
                   } else if(i2.hasNext()) {
                       return i2.next();
                   } else {
                       throw new NoSuchElementException("Lists exhausted");
                   }
               }
               public void remove() {
                   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is: [`com.google.common.collect.Iterables#concat()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29)

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now 404.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has the following method on [`LazyIterate`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/LazyIterate.html).

```
public static <T> LazyIterable<T> concatenate(Iterable<T>... iterables)
```

Any [`LazyIterable`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/LazyIterable.html) can concatenate itself with another iterable as well using the following method.

```
LazyIterable<T> concatenate(Iterable<T> iterable)
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.